# Why does my link change color to red briefly after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box called Audience Demographics, Inside my modal box are a set of main genres which open up another modal box that contains my sub genres.

The problem is that when the user clicks on a main genre (e.g Demographics), briefly before the next modal box opens the main genre (e.g Demographics) will quickly change font color to red.

Now the font color should not be changing for any of my main genres period.

Furthermore to this, it would seem that the font color for my main genres isn't changing even when I go as far as manually implementing a color:white code into the html element (The sub genres are supposed to be white not blue).

May I please get some help on whats wrong.

```js
// maintains a sticky pop up (original code)
$('a[href="#ex6-1b"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
});

// allows mutliple modals
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex6-2bc"],a[href="#ex6-2b"],a[href="#ex6-3b"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    closeExisting: true,
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: white
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.your-divs {
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px
}

.blackBox {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-family: nunito;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div class="blackBox" data-name="audience">
  <a class="btn" href="#ex6-1b" style="color:white"> <b> Audience Demographics </b> </a>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="ex6-1b" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px; color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <p> <a href="#ex6-2bc"><b>Demographics</b></a> </p>
      <p> <a href="#ex6-2b"><b>LGBTQ</b></a> </p>
      <p> <a href="#ex6-3b"><b>BAME</b></a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese;"> <b>Return</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="ex6-2bc" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group19"> <label for="group19" class="onlyThese" name="male"> <b> Cis Male </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group29"> <label for="group29" class="onlyThese" name="female"> <b> Cis Female </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group39"> <label for="group39" class="onlyThese" name="non-binary"> <b> Non Binary </b> </label> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="ex6-2b" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group10"> <label for="group10" class="onlyThese" name="gay"> <b> Gay </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group20"> <label for="group40" class="onlyThese" name="lesbian"> <b> Lesbian </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group30"> <label for="group30" class="onlyThese" name="bisexual"> <b> Bisexual </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group40"> <label for="group40" class="onlyThese" name="bisexual"> <b> Transgender </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group50"> <label for="group50" class="onlyThese" name="queer_non_conforming"> <b> Queer Non-Conforming </b> </label> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="ex6-3b" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group11"> <label for="group11" class="onlyThese" name="mix_multiple_ethic"> <b> Mixed / Multiple Ethnic </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group22"> <label for="group22" class="onlyThese" name="asian_british_asian"> <b> Asian / British Asian  </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group33"> <label for="group33" class="onlyThese" name="black_african_caribbean"> <b> Black African / Black Caribbean </b> </label> </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group44"> <label for="group44" class="onlyThese" name="other_ethic_group"> <b> Other Ethnic Group </b> </label> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that you do not defining any style for `a` and it have default styles, if you specified style for `a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active` you should be able achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red is the default for an active link

Add

```
a:visited { color:yellow }
a:active { color:pink }
```

if you want to change the colours

```js
// maintains a sticky pop up (original code)
$('a[href="#ex6-1b"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,

  });
});


// allows mutliple modals
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex6-2bc"],a[href="#ex6-2b"],a[href="#ex6-3b"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    closeExisting: true,
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
a:visited { color:yellow }
a:active { color:pink }

.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: white
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.your-divs {
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px
}

.blackBox {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-family: nunito;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />






<div class="blackBox" data-name="audience">
  <a class="btn" href="#ex6-1b" style="color:white"> <b> Audience Demographics </b> </a>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="ex6-1b" style="display:none; background-color:black">

  <div style="float:left;">

    <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px; color:white; text-transform:uppercase">

      <p> <a href="#ex6-2bc"><b>Demographics</b></a> </p>

      <p> <a href="#ex6-2b"><b>LGBTQ</b></a> </p>

      <p> <a href="#ex6-3b"><b>BAME</b></a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese;"> <b>Return</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="ex6-2bc" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group19"> <label for="group19" class="onlyThese" name="male"> <b> Cis Male </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group29"> <label for="group29" class="onlyThese" name="female"> <b> Cis Female </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group39"> <label for="group39" class="onlyThese" name="non-binary"> <b> Non Binary </b> </label> </p>



  </div>

  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="ex6-2b" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group10"> <label for="group10" class="onlyThese" name="gay"> <b> Gay </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group20"> <label for="group40" class="onlyThese" name="lesbian"> <b> Lesbian </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group30"> <label for="group30" class="onlyThese" name="bisexual"> <b> Bisexual </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group40"> <label for="group40" class="onlyThese" name="bisexual"> <b> Transgender </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group50"> <label for="group50" class="onlyThese" name="queer_non_conforming"> <b> Queer Non-Conforming </b> </label> </p>


  </div>

  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal" id="ex6-3b" style="display:none; background-color:black">
  <div style="line-height:1.8; font-size:16px">

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group11"> <label for="group11" class="onlyThese" name="mix_multiple_ethic"> <b> Mixed / Multiple Ethnic </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group22"> <label for="group22" class="onlyThese" name="asian_british_asian"> <b> Asian / British Asian  </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group33"> <label for="group33" class="onlyThese" name="black_african_caribbean"> <b> Black African / Black Caribbean </b> </label> </p>

    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group44"> <label for="group44" class="onlyThese" name="other_ethic_group"> <b> Other Ethnic Group </b> </label> </p>


  </div>

  <div class="your-divs">
    <p style="color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="onlyThese"> <b>Apply</b></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it :\